# 3-way control slider using Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to a 3-way control using Swiper slide.

What do I mean saying 3-way. There is a 2-way control `http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/23-thumbs-gallery.html` example, but I need 3rd row with content. May be anyone has the idea?

I made a 3rd row,

```
  var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
      spaceBetween: 10,
  });
  var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
  });
  var galleryTabs = new Swiper('.swiper-tabs',{
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  });

galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryTabs.params.control = galleryTop;
```

But 3rd row slides when user scrolls `galleryTop` only. When user scrolls `galleryThumbs` there are no changes with 3rd row
When users scrolls 3rd row, slides `galleryTop` and `galleryThumbs`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding listeners for `onSlideChangeStart` to my galleryTop and  - it slides the "third wheel" to the active index. The other way around, once the user swipes on the third swiper, the other two instances are sliding to the active index of that one. It's slightly confusing to write this in theory, so here's the code. I left the `params.control`-assignment in place, to show that coexistence is possible. But I guess it is cleaner to solve this entirely through the `onSlideChange` events.

```
 var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 10,
  onSlideChangeStart: function(){
                galleryTabs.slideTo(galleryTop.activeIndex);
            }    
  });

  var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
  });
  var galleryTabs = new Swiper('.swiper-tabs',{
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
      onSlideChangeStart: function(){
                galleryTop.slideTo(galleryTabs.activeIndex);
                galleryThumbs.slideTo(galleryTabs.activeIndex);
            }   
  });

galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each next instance of slider should be controlled by previous:

```
// galleryTop and galleryThumbs 
galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;

// galleryThumbs and galleryTabs 
galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTabs ;
galleryTabs.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
```